# wifi network not showing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am new to ubuntu, recently installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on laptop.

After install my wifi network is not showing up on the laptop.

Need help.

Thanks 
Arun

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: See [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](http://askubuntu.com/q/425155), and please add the necessary information to your question so we know what the problem is. At a minimum, we'd at least need to know the model of the laptop.

Comment: can you try to find results of # rfkill list all , if the command return blocked card soft block or hard block , unblock it by # rfkill unblock all , if you didn't find any blocked try to enable wifi using nmcli # nmcli radio wifi on .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you may need to dig a little deeper. I'd start out by restarting your network manager by typing:
`sudo service network-manager restart`.

Answer (score -1):

Your wifi network may not be listed first in the list of available networks. Look down the entire list. Also check the list of hidden networks. If you still don't see your wifi network, try to disable and re-enable the network. The latest kernel update to 4.4.0-22 works better at detecting and connecting to wifi networks. If you can connect to the internet over a wired interface, be sure to update and down load any upgrades. In a terminal window, enter sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade

You may need to enter your log on password.